# Optimal cutree for partially matching string

Tags: r, machine-learning, tree

I am comparing strings together and I am trying to identify the optimal number of clusters. I have the following dataset:

```
d <- structure(list(Fund = structure(c(8L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("Branch April China", "Branch April Europe", 
"Branch April US", "Branch Emerging Markets EUR", "Branch Emerging Markets GBP", 
"Branch Emerging Markets JPY", "Branch Emerging Markets USD", 
"Branch EUR", "Branch GBP", "Branch JPY", "Branch USD"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Fund", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I computed the Levenshtein distances as follows and performing a hierarchical cluster

```
  dist <- adist(d$Fund)
  rownames(dist) <- d$Fund
  colnames(dist) <- d$Fund
  hc <- hclust(as.dist(dist))
```

Now, I want to identify the optimal number of clusters using the following command:

```
df <- data.frame(d$Fund,cutree(hc,2))
```

I have done some reading about finding the optimal number of cluster but it's more related to `kmeans` command. how is it possible to find the optimal number of cluster in my example? Thanks a lot for your precious help

Comment: Have a look at package NbClust.

Comment: i have thanks, do you have any cluse how to implement it using string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took this from the package NbClust. I looked at the help pages and dived into the examples. In your case, you have a dissimilarity matrix (distances), hence I took the following code:

```
library(NbClust)

# for reproducibility
set.seed(1)

# create some data
x<-rbind(matrix(rnorm(150,sd=0.3),ncol=3),
     matrix(rnorm(150,mean=3,sd=0.2),ncol=3),
     matrix(rnorm(150,mean=5,sd=0.3),ncol=3))

# produce dissimilarity matrix of the data
diss_matrix<- dist(x, method = "euclidean", diag=FALSE)
res<-NbClust(x, diss=diss_matrix, distance = NULL, min.nc=2, max.nc=6, 
         method = "ward.D", index = "ch")  
res$All.index
res$Best.nc
res$Best.partition
```

You can copy and run the code after installing the package. The best number of clusters is given by `res$Best.nc`, and the cluster-indices by `res$Best.partition`.

You need to read a lot more information than what I can give you here. Reading the NbClust pamflet seems like a good beginning. Good luck!